# How to sum values within nested foreach loops?

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream

How can a sum be calcaulated using `stream` api with nested foreach loops where each has a filter condition?

```
//java7
Double sum = null; 
for (FirstNode first : response.getFirstNodes()) {
    if (first.isValid()) {
        for (SndNnode snd : first.getSndNodes()) {
            if (snd.getType() == NodeType.AMOUNT) {
                sum += snd.getAmount();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

//java8
response.getFirstNodes().stream().filter(first -> first.isValid()).mapToDouble(???).sum();
```

My snd foreach loop would be:

```
first.getSndNodes().stream().filter(snd -> snd.getType() == NodeType.AMOUNT).mapToDouble(snd -> snd.getAmount()).findFirst().sum();
```

How could I now integrate the snd foreach loop into the first, to get a global sum of the nested lists?

Comment: I think the `break;` statement is redundant

Comment: Not if `getSndNodes()` returns a really large list and I only want to get the first/only result. But of course this really applies only to very large lists, and will most of the time have no impact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `flatMap`:

```
response.getFirstNodes()
        .stream()
        .filter(first -> first.isValid())
        .flatMap(first -> first.getSndNodes().stream())
        .filter(snd -> snd.getType() == NodeType.AMOUNT)
        .mapToDouble(snd -> snd.getAmount())
        .sum();
```

I'm not sure whether that `break;` is intentional in your original code.

---

With the `break;` statement, it should looks like this:

```
response.getFirstNodes()
                .stream()
                .filter(first -> first.isValid())
                .map(first -> first.getSndNodes().stream().filter(snd -> snd.getType() == NodeType.AMOUNT).findFirst())
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .mapToDouble(opt -> opt.get().getAmount())
                .sum();
```

Basically, for each `FirstNode` you test whether it's valid, then you map each `FirstNode` to a stream of its `SndNode`s for which you find the first that has the type `NodeType.AMOUNT`. You need then to filter to get only Optionals that are not empty and for them you get the `SndNode` they contains for which you get the corresponding amount.

Comment: The `break` is intended as I have to iterate a large list and can ensure my condition always will only fit one single element. So, if found the most inner loop should break. But from your answers I assume this inner short circuit is not possible with stream api?

Comment: Ok but then your second for-each translation is not the same as the original code because it'll sum all the values of each snd instances that are AMOUNT instead of the first one in the original code.

Comment: Oh thanks, I added the `findFirst()` to my post now to make it clear.

Answer (score 4):

Your attempt is close to the right solution

```
response.getFirstNodes().stream()
.filter(FirstNode::isValid)
.mapToDouble(first ->
   first.getSndNodes().stream()
        .filter(snd -> snd.getType() == NodeType.AMOUNT)
        .mapToDouble(snd -> snd.getAmount())
        .findAny().orElse(0))
.sum();
```

If you are sure that there is at most one match in the inner stream, you can use `findAny` as there is no requirement on the ordering then. I used the simplest solution for dealing with the possible absence of a match by replacing it with `0` which is transparent to the `sum` and saves us from additional filtering.

Answer (score 2):

You can use flatMap to create a single Stream of all the inner lists :

```
response.getFirstNodes()
        .stream()
        .filter (first -> first.isValid())
        .flatMap (first -> first.getSndNodes().stream())
        .filter(snd -> snd.getType() == NodeType.AMOUNT)
        .mapToDouble(snd -> snd.getAmount())
        .sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) the nested nodes. For example:

```
response.getFirstNodes().stream()
                        .filter(FirstNode::isValid)
                        .flatMap(first -> first.getSndNodes().stream())
                        .filter(snd -> snd.getType == NodeType.AMOUNT)
                        .mapToDouble(SndNode::getAmount)
                        .sum();
```